# How do I manage two java dispatcher in one project?

Tags: java, url-mapping

I have two Spring MVC projects.  I want to merge *Project b* into *Project a*.

*Project a*'s dispatcher servlet configuation:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.web" />

    <bean
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

*Project b*'s dispatcher servlet configuration:

```
...
<bean id="webDispatcherMapping"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping"
          lazy-init="true">
        <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true" />
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="/web">#{webDispatcherMappingSystem}</prop>
                <prop key="/web/**">#{webDispatcherMappingSystem}</prop>
                <prop key="/web/resources/**">#{webDispatcherMappingSystem}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
...
```

Now I want to merge *Project B* into *Project a*. 
My problem is the URL mapping. I want to map `/` to *Project a* , and map `/web` to *Project b*.
I want to merge these two mappings into *Project a*`s dispatcher servlet configuration.

**How do I do? No body can help me?**